# Why is a query with indexes not a covered query?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query, query-optimization

You would like to perform a covered query on the `example` collection. You have the following indexes:

```
{ name : 1, dob : 1 }
{ _id : 1 }
{ hair : 1, name : 1 }
```

Why is the below query not a [covered query](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_covered_queries.htm)?

```
db.example.find( { name : { $in : [ "Bart", "Homer" ] } }, {_id : 0, hair : 1, name : 1} )
```

While this one is:

```
db.example.find( { name : { $in : [ "Bart", "Homer" ] } }, {_id : 0, dob : 1, name : 1} )
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this question. I'm on the same problem from M101JS. The lecturer didn't talk about the order of the fields when creating the index and in the "explanation" of the answer he only makes a very brief reference to the idea by calling it a "left subset"... A term he seems to have made up.

Comment: @Vince I'm glad that it helped...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to documentation on [index prefixes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#prefixes), the query

```
db.example.find( { name : { $in : [ "Bart", "Homer" ] } } );
```

will be covered by

```
db.example.createIndex({ "name": 1, "dob": 1 });
```

but not by

```
db.example.createIndex({ "hair": 1, "name": 1 });
```

since `{ "name": 1 }` is not the preifx of `{ "hair": 1, "name": 1 }`.

**Sample**

```
{ "_id": 1, "name": "Bart", "hair": "triangles", "dob": "1985-01-01" }
{ "_id": 2, "name": "Homer", "hair": "two", "dob": "1960-01-01" }
```

**Query 1**

```
> db.example.find(
>     { name: { $in: [ "Bart", "Homer" ] } }, 
>     { _id: 0, hair: 1, name: 1 }
> ).explain("executionStats");
...
"executionStats": {
    "totalKeysExamined": 2,
    "totalDocsExamined": 2,
    "executionStages": {
        "stage": "PROJECTION",
        "inputStage": {
            "stage": "FETCH",
            "inputStage": {
                "stage": "IXSCAN",
                "indexName": "name_1_dob_1",
                ...
```

As you see, `name_1_dob_1` index was used (since `{ "name": 1 }` is the prefix of `{ "name": 1, "dob": 1 }`, 2 documents were examined in the index (`"totalKeysExamined": 2`), and then 2 documents were examined in the collection (`"totalDocsExamined": 2`), since `name_1_dob_1` index does not have information about `hair` that is required to return.

**Query 2**

```
> db.example.find(
>     { name: { $in: [ "Bart", "Homer" ] } }, 
>     { _id: 0, dob: 1, name: 1 }
> ).explain("executionStats");
...
"executionStats": {
    "totalKeysExamined": 2,
    "totalDocsExamined": 0,
    "executionStages": {
        "stage": "PROJECTION",
        "inputStage": {
            "stage": "IXSCAN",
            "indexName": "name_1_dob_1",
            ...
```

As for the Query 1, index `name_1_dob_1` was used and 2 documents were examined in the index (`"totalKeysExamined": 2`), but there were no call to the collection (`"totalDocsExamined": 0`), since index `name_1_dob_1` contains both `dob` and `name` in it and there are no need to fetch something more from the collection.

Comment: Thanks, be happy :)